# Angular services are not so singleton

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-services, angular-library

I'm developping an Angular7 app. In my project, I've several libraries some of them containing services.

Let's say I've a service called `NotificatorService` in a library called `lib-controls`

```
import { Notifications } from './notifications.enum';
import { INotificationService } from './notification-service.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

//service in charge of notification handling
export class NotificatorService implements INotificationService {

    //notifications array
    notifications: Array<any> = new Array<any>();

    constructor() {
        console.log('init');
    }

    //when a notifaction is displayed
    notify(keyword: Notifications) {
        console.log(keyword);
        this.notifications.push(keyword);
    }
}
```

Still in my `lib-controls` library I've several controls that injects this service such as this one:

```
import { Notifications } from '../../../../notifications/notifications.enum';
import { NotificatorService } from '../../../../notifications/notificator.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'send-mail',
  templateUrl: './send-mail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./send-mail.component.css']
})

export class SendMailComponent {

    constructor(private _notificationService: NotificatorService) {

    }

    notifyMailState(keyword: Notification) {
         this._notificationService.notify(keyword);
    }
}
```

Now from my app component I'd also like to inject this service to send notifications

```
import { NotificatorService } from 'lib-controls';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [{ provide: SendMailAbstract, useClass: SendmailService }, { 
provide: SendUsbAbstract, useClass: SendUsbService }]
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(
    private _notificatorService: NotificatorService) {
  }

  notify() {
    this._notificatorService.notify(<Notifications>('OFFLINE'));
  }
}
```

Note that the import is now not a relative path but targeting the library directly.

What I can see from here, is that the service seems to be instantiated twice.
One for all the injects from the `lib-controls` and one for the app itself.

[image]

Here we can see that we've two differents paths as well for the same service.

This leads to the fact that my `notifications` array doesn't contain all of my notifications but notifications per my app in one of the instance of the service and notifications per the `lib-controls` library on the other hand.

I'd like to have only one instance of the service one the whole application, no matter how the service is imported (relative or from the lib)

I tried to play with `providers` in my module but nothing really changes. Although I thought that the `providedIn: root` would do the trick but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: are you sure that you have not added the service to  Provider of any of your component or module , other than specifying `providedIn: 'root'` in the service

Comment: please check your `lib-controls` library i think you must have added  `providers: [NotificatorService]` somewhere (cause you need to export the service  in order to be available along with library)

Comment: @JoelJoseph nothing is set in the providers properties..